# Unmarshalling XML child array into direct Go struct array

Tags: xml, go, unmarshalling

I have an XML object like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<directory count="2">
<entries>
    <entry name="Alice"/>
    <entry name="Bob"/>
</entries>
</directory>
```

Now I want to parse this into a Go struct that looks like this:

```
type Entry struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"entry"`
    Name    string   `xml:"name,attr"`
}

type Directory struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"directory"`
    Count   string   `xml:"count,attr"`
    Entries []Entry  `xml:"entries"`
}
```

As you can see, I'd like **Entries** to be a direct child of **Directory**. This does not work, `Directory.Entries` is always empty.

It does however work when I add some kind of proxy object like this (got this from an XML->Go struct converter [found here](https://xml-to-go.github.io/)):

```
type Directory struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"directory"`
    Text    string   `xml:",chardata"`
    Count   string   `xml:"count,attr"`
    Entries struct {
        Text  string `xml:",chardata"`
        Entry []struct {
            Text string `xml:",chardata"`
            Name string `xml:"name,attr"`
        } `xml:"entry"`
    } `xml:"entries"`
}
```

In this version, the array gets filled and I can access a given entry at index `i` via `Directory.Entries.Entry[i]`.

How can I omit the unneccessary object here and access the entries directly via `Directory.Entries[i]`? Is it possible without building a custom (un)marshaller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the parent>child>plant tag `>` from the xml definition on the entries collection:

```
Entries []Entry  `xml:"entries>entry"`
```

Go Play: https://go.dev/play/p/4SZT8-S8BFF

Comment: That's it! Thanks! Must have missed that.